# Finding a View with IViewFor<InterfaceClass> from a class VM that implements InterfaceClass?

Tags: mvvm, reactiveui

I have the following class which is my view model (this is very simple right now, but it will contain a chunk more logic eventually):

```
    public class IndicoTalk : ITalk
    {
        private Talk _talk;

        public IndicoTalk(Talk t)
        {
            this._talk = t;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _talk.Title; }
        }
    }
```

Now, I have a reactive ui view for this guy:

```
public sealed partial class TalkView : UserControl, IViewFor<ITalk>
{
    public TalkView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.Title, y => y.TalkTitle.Text);
    }
```

Note that the IViewFor is for ITalk, not IndicoTalk. This is because I can have other types of talk, and they will all fit into the same view.

And I register this ViewModel in my App start up:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new TalkView(),
        typeof(IViewFor<IWalker.DataModel.Inidco.IndicoMeetingRef.IndicoTalk>));
```

Finally, in another viewmodel I have a ReactiveList which contains a bunch of these IndicoTalks's. Of course, when I bind this to a ListBox, ReactiveUI fails to find the view. If I switch to IViewFor then everything works just fine.

What is the proper way to gently redirect the view resolution in this case?

A half-way solution: leave all code above the same, but put in the IViewFor ITalk instead of IndicoTalk. This works, but means I will have to register with Splat (the CurrentMutable call above) every ViewModel that inherrits from ITalk. I'd love to avoid that if possible!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, why not just do:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new TalkView(), typeof(IViewFor<ITalk>));
```

Comment: I get the exception "Couldn't find view for 'IWalker.DataModel.Inidco.IndicoMeetingRef+IndicoTalk'." from ViewModelIViewHost.